# .Net SMBv2 Client library

Tags: .net, xamarin.forms, smb, jcifs, cifs

I have been looking for ways to read/write to shared folders in a Windows Machine via my **Xamarin.Forms** App.

So far I found two **.Net** libraries that i thought would solve my problem: [SharpCifs](https://github.com/ume05rw/SharpCifs.Std) and [Xamarin.Android.jCIFS](https://github.com/sushihangover/Xamarin.Android.jCIFS) nevertheless, they are a porting and a binding of JCIFS respectively and as stated in [this info](https://lists.samba.org/archive/jcifs/2013-December/010123.html) JCIFS only supports SMB1 which is being deactivated from many Windows Machines since WCRY (as soon as I disable SMB1 on the remote PC, those libraries stop working.)

So, is there any .NET SMBv2+ Client Library available? Or, What would be an alternative to achieve this task (read/write to shared folders in a Windows Machine via my **Xamarin.Forms** App)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visuality Systems sells two SMB2/3 libraries. One (NQE) is a C lib and can be ported to .NET. Another one, jNQ is pure Java. In bot cases, you will need to develop a thin .NET wrapper.

Comment: It Looks like a good alternative in case that there isn't really a .Net library out there...
Anyway, do you know how is it with the NQ library's license, would it be legal to bind it or port it? Would i have to buy the library and make the wrapper my self? Or what would you suggest in order to get the .Net Wrapper?

Answer (score 0):

NQE is shipped in sources so it is easier to modify. jNQ is shipped in binaries, however, it is easier to use. Also JNQ may be chipper, imho. I am not an expert in writing .NET wrappers but I do not see issues in either approach. Just to know that both SMB libraries are using threads internally.